# How is this possible? Ruby if loop fails

Tags: ruby

I don't understand how this can be:

```
 (byebug) missing_association_words.include?(@mtw.first.word)
 false
 (byebug) @mtw.first.word
 text
 (byebug) missing_association_words
 text
```

This piece of code returns `false` although both contain the same value.

Comment: are both `@mtw.first.word` and `missing_association_words` of String class?

Comment: Worth checking for whitespace after `text` too.

Comment: `missing_association_words` is an array and `@mtw` is also an array.

Comment: Could you post them?

Comment: you are actually comparing two arrays for identical values. I posted an answer how you could do that

Comment: glad u used RUBY inside the title - but sad u tagged it with rails!

Comment: What is the type of `@mtw.first.word` and what is the type of `missing_association_words.first`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the values from the second array are also included in the first array, you can use this:

```
(first_array & second_array).any?
```